# How to create a desktop shortcut to an MTP folder on an Android smartphone?

Tags: windows, android, shortcuts, mtp

My LG G2 Android smartphone can connect via MTP. I would like to make a shortcut to its internal downloads folder:

```
Computer\LG_G2\Internal storage\Download\
```

How to do that?

Comment: Erm, why should this question be off topic (not about computer hardware/software)?   It's tagged with Windows and Shortcuts. It's a valid question as I see it

Comment: I don't think a shortcut is possible; MTP devices does not have "files & folders" in the same sense as a filsystem (e.g. NTFS) has it.

Comment: Related: [How do I access MTP devices on the command line in Windows?](http://superuser.com/a/377008/50173). I googled around a bit to see if Powershell can utilize a Win32 class and somehow access the MTP device. No luck so far. Seems hard/impossible

Comment: Well thanks I figured it out it's not possible. When I manually create a shortcut in the desktop it adds C:\ to beginning of the line and if removed says "The file xxx could not be found"

Answer (score 6):

maybe this thread is old, but i think I found the solution for the question.
This worked for me in Windows 7 64 bit with a MOTO G(5) with Android 7

- Connect your cellphone through MTP to the computer.
- From Windows explorer right click your cellphone folder, and select copy.
- In your windows desktop right click and select paste as a shortcut.

Voila, that did the trick for me.

Best Regards!

Comment: I didn't know about 'paste as shortcut', working for me too!

Comment: This answer works brilliant and is still relevant as of 2021!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!

Comment: @progonkpa You can drag&drop any file/directory/item to the desktop and press `ALT` at the same time. It would make shortcut instead of a copy. Then drag&drop created shortcut back to the target folder. It is faster because no need to open the target folder to create a shortcut from a source.

Answer (score 0):

Just for instance, there is another answer from `stackoverflow`.

> There is a way to open an MTP device folder directly in the Windows Explorer window on Windows 7 x64.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397348/open-folder-on-portable-device-with-batch-file/65997169#65997169