# How to assign a drive letter to a Windows Portable Device?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, usb

Asking the "[How to assign a drive letter to a Portable Device?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-assign-a-drive-letter-to-a-portable-device/829e43b6-7210-4566-8e47-1ac147946f7b)" question again here as the *"answer"* there points to *nowhere* now.

The problem I'm facing is exactly the same. I.e., I need to view the images on the Portable Device coming from my attached smartphone. I don't like the new Windows Photo app at all and I've removed it, but none of the Windows image viewers I found can deal with such Portable Device. Moreover, images from anywhere on my disk can be drag&dropped (as attachment to my emails for e.g.), but those under the Portable Device folders can't.

Original question:

> I have a Canon Digital Rebel XSi and ...  When I connect the camera via USB, it shows up just fine under Portable Devices.  The problem is that the filepath is Computer\Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XSi.  I cannot get any third-party software to recognize that as a valid filepath (because it does not begin with something like F:), nor can I find any way of getting Windows 7 to assign a drive letter to the camera directly.
>
> Is there a way to either assign a drive letter to the camera or get third-party software to recognize Computer\Canon EOS DIGITAL REBEL XSi as a valid filepath?

The "Most Helpful Reply" there was:

If it appears in the 'Portable Devices' section of My Computer, it doesn't get a drive letter - and it doesn't need a new driver either, it's working - at least as far as Microsoft is concerned

The problem is, some apps don't recognise these Computer\DeviceName\Folder paths

I've also noticed that Windows has issues with these folders too. When you have a folder full of images, viewing 'Large Icons' doesn't show a preview of the image - just the icon for the image type.

Yet again, Microsoft has released half finished functionality on us.
There was nothing wrong with assigning drive letters, or at least having the option to assign a drive letter in case you have too many devices to have them all assigned at once.
Instead they have released a new method of connecting to a portable device but have not provided all the functionality needed to allow these new drives to work properly

Comment: Have you tried using disk management?

Comment: When a device connects and it does not get a driveletter assigned, this is the fault of the driver not doing so, not windoiws or Microsoft.

Comment: @LPChip, you have an example of Windows Portable Device getting a driveletter assigned, with the help of a good device driver?

Comment: @Superuser_do, Have you? Got any luck?

Comment: @xpt I haven't tried but you could see if it appears in Disk Management and assign a letter.

Comment: @xpt yeah. My flashdrive gets a driveletter assigned, but I also seen one that didn't. But I didn't need a driveletter back then, so I never looked for it in disk management. But in the past I once got a drive without letter and was able to assign it.

Comment: @LPChip, flashdrives are just normal disks, and should be treated so (with no exceptions, else it's a bug). However, we're talking about attaching camera or smartphone here, which are shown under the "Portable Device" section.

Comment: @Superuser_do, no such luck.

Comment: Does that use MTP? If yes, somewhat dup of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/369959/230773).

Answer (score 1):

I have found this from the Microsoft community website

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-to-assign-a-drive-letter-to-a-portable-device/829e43b6-7210-4566-8e47-1ac147946f7b?page=2

Try using http://www.mtpdrive.com... It should do the trick....

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful in my opionion.  You should quote and cite the relevant information from your link or improve your question in some other significant way.

Comment: @Ramhound This is not actually a link only answer. It tells to use the mtpdrive software, which enables mapping a MTP device to a drive letter. It could have been more explicit though. (And I have not tried it, there is a "purchase" tab on the software site. I am unwilling to buy a software while I can just manage my phone from my linux box instead of the windows one, lacking that basic feature.)

Comment: Newer answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1724634