# How can I assign a letter drive to a Digital camera, after I connect via USB?

Tags: windows, batch

I need to assign to an SD Card of a digital camera, when I connect it via USB to my PC.
At the moment, Windows 10 show me: "SD-CARD" but no letter drive.

I need a letter drive because I've created a script to automatically download photo and backup it etc...

Comment: If the device uses MTP, this [may not be easy](https://superuser.com/a/377008/432690). See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1138782/432690).

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by opening the Computer Maganement plug-in of the Microsoft Management Console with

<kbd>Win</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>diskmgmt.msc<kbd>Enter</kbd>

If asked, enter the Administrator password, or confirm you want to run it as administrator.

Right-click on the SSD Card, and pick **Change Drive Letter and Paths**, then choose **Add**, select a letter different than any of your existing drive letters and then click OK.

I'd avoid A: or B: since you may use that camera with another app someday, and I have read some older apps can act strangely if they see a drive A; or B: larger than a standard floppy disc.

Close the Disk Management console, and your device should appear with that drive letter henceforth.

Comment: When I right click on it, "Change Drive Letter and Paths" is grayed out.