# Why can't i see my USB drive?

Tags: windows, boot, usb

I can't see my USB drive (SanDisk 16GB) in the Explorer. The stick has no problem on other PCs but on my Laptop it shows up in cmd or device manager etc. but not in the explorer or 3rd party programs. I already formatted it (not quick). The last thing I did (before the problem occurred) was to use it as a boot stick with "Universal USB installer 2.0.0.5"

Comment: It might just be that you need to go into Disk Management and assign a drive letter to the USB stick: https://superuser.com/questions/1355859/how-can-i-assign-a-letter-drive-to-a-digital-camera-after-i-connect-via-usb?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the partition layout

Comment: In older Windows versions there was a registry option to hide certain drive letters in Windows Explorer. Not sure if this still exists in the Windows version you use (what ever version you use, you forgot to tell us this important detail).

Comment: @Mokubai, yes now it's working. Thank you