# Syncing between C drive and phone with robocopy

Tags: windows, command-line, android, robocopy

I'm on Windows 10 and trying to sync my music folder with the one on my LG G5. My plan is to use `robocopy /mir`, but I don't know how to write out a path to the directory on my phone. The phone's set to file transfer mode, so I can navigate to it in Windows Explorer through This PC > G5 > Internal storage. But there's not a drive letter or anything so I'm not sure what the command line path is.  Is this even possible?

Since someone asked, the `list volume` command in `diskpart` outputted the following:

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type       Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ---------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     D                       DVD-ROM        0 B  No Media
Volume 1                      NTFS   Partition   350 MB  Healthy    System
Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition   439 GB  Healthy    Boot
```

As you can see, the phone isn't listed.

Comment: What shows Diskpart on commandline?

Comment: @GiaRui I'm not very familiar with diskpart. What command(s) would help me answer your question?

Comment: Go to "start" in search type "cmd" right click on it and start as Administartor. Then type in the commandline Diskpart, as Diskpart is ready, type "list volume" to see the devices(partitions).

Comment: @GiaRui I've added that output.

Comment: Why robocopy when you could use a more intuitive GUI based **SYNCTOY** [SYNCTOY](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=15155). I presume this will match your requirements more in this case

Comment: @pulsarjune My intention was to write a batch script so I can sync the files simply by running the script. Anyways, does synctoy support MTP and PTP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.** You’re accessing the phone using [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) or [PTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol). They are not filesystem access protocols but rather object storage protocols. The objects just happen to have a 1:1 mapping to files on your phone.

Somebody asked a related question, [How do I access MTP devices on the command line in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/369959/219095) The answer is:

> Unfortunately, APIs exposed by MTP are very different from a normal filesystem APIs. Therefore exposing MTP device as a read/write filesystem is not possible.

Of course, this also applies to all GUI tools that are not explicitly MTP-aware.